# How can I add the 'Glow effect' to UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem, glow

I tried a lot to find out the glow effect for UIBarButtonItem.  Now am doing by creating a UIButton and making it as the customView for the UIBarButton. Do anyone have any other methods to make it much more easier? (like a inbuilt property for UIBarButtonItem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mean the effect you get when you touch an button? That is a property on an UIButton (also accessible from Interface Builder);

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL showsTouchWhenHighlighted
```

So...

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.showsTouchWhenHighlighted = YES;
```

If you write a subclass of UIBarButtonItem and put this code in there somewhere it is really easy (and not messy) to re-use it. I'm not sure if there is any other way.

Comment: friend, I know the method to make the UIButton to glow. The question is how can I add glow effect to the UIBarButton without custonViewing the UIButton to it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`- (id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action`

as button style using `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain`