# how can i make a glow effect around button

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I add the 'Glow effect' to UIBarButtonItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884538/how-can-i-add-the-glow-effect-to-uibarbuttonitem)

I want to make a glow effect around my button as in info light button through coding. How can I get it.

Comment: See this [Stackoverflow question][1]. All the best. [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884538/how-can-i-add-the-glow-effect-to-uibarbuttonitem

Comment: Thank you Warrior and i am sorry i post this question.Its my fault that i didn't do a good search.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but i think you can try this

Create a new image similar to the glow called glowImage.png and

```
[yourButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"glowImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```